# React typescript ref.current is possible null. Why?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my react typescript app I have this code:

```
  const inputRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const onIconClick = () => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      setTimeout(() => inputRef.current.focus(), 0);
    }
  };
```

Typescript highlights ***inputRef.current***.focus() with text:

```
const inputRef: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>
Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)
```

But I do "null checking"...

I also tried this construction:

```
  const inputRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null) as MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>
```

But I got error when I tried to pass ref to child component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ref may have changed in between your checking of `if (inputRef.current) {` and the call to `.focus()`. Either do

```
setTimeout(() => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
        inputRef.current.focus();
    }
}, 0);
```

or, more concisely, use optional chaining.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    inputRef.current?.focus();
}, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Type guards remain in effect across function boundaries only when the guarded variables are considered constant. So use `const`:

```
    const el = inputRef.current
    if (el) {
        setTimeout(() => el.focus(), 0);
    }
```

Check inside a function is OK too only if you do not care about `setTimeout` extra call:

```
   setTimeout(() => inputRef.current?.focus(), 0);
```